# Change wordpress admin home page

Tags: wp-admin

I would like to change the `/wp-admin/index.php` default page to something like `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page` so that when a user logs in, they get redirected to `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page` instead of `/wp-admin/index.php`. I will appreciate guides on this

Answer (score 0):

There's a filter called `login_redirect` where you can change the URL users get redirected to after logging in.

There's a nice example in the comments of the documentation page here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/

Here's a suggestion of how you could modify it to do what you want:

```
function wpdocs_my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ) {
    if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
        if ( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $url = home_url('/YOUR/CUSTOM/URL/HERE');
        } 
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpdocs_my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Note this code untested, let me know if you try it and have problems.